# Confused about char and char * and scanning in words

Tags: c, if-statement, char, int, scanf

I wrote this simple code which scans in some numbers and words. However, I am confused because the char always give me an error. What is wrong with it?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int val_pos, incr_val, max_val;
    char *file_name;
    char *new_name;

    if (argc == 6) {

        val_pos = atoi(argv[1]);
        incr_val = atoi(argv[2]);
        max_val = atoi(argv[3]);
        file_name = argv[4];
        new_name = argv[5];

    } else {

        printf("Command usage: %s <val_pos> <increment val> <max val> <file_name> <new name>\n", argv[0]);

        printf("What is the position you want to change? Enter your number\n");
        printf("X = 0 | Y = 1 | Z = 2\n");
        scanf("%d", &val_pos);

        printf("What is the increment value?\n");
        scanf("%d", &incr_val);

        printf("What is the max value/value we should terminate at?\n");
        scanf("%d", &max_val);

        printf("What is the pose file called?\n");
        scanf("%s", &file_name);

        printf("What should we call the newly generated files?\n");
        scanf("%s", &new_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "chars always give you an error"?

Comment: `file_name` and `new_name` are initially *Uninitialized Pointers* to which to assign the address of `argv[4]` and `argv[5]`. When you attempt to `scanf("%s", &file_name);` you are writing back to  `argv[4]`. While the C-standard requires that the `argv` value are modifiable -- you cannot write beyond the the bounds of the original values. So if the name you input is longer than the original -- you likely invoke *Undefined Behavior* overwriting the original *nul-terminating* character and writing outside the bounds of the original allocation for the argument. The `&` is also wrong.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so how can I scan in the file_name?

Comment: Declare `char file_name[512] = "";` to create automatic storage for your new names and then `scanf("%s", file_name);` (no `'&'`, `file_name` is already a pointer) Adjust the size as required.

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov: Perhaps start with reading [`scanf()`'s documentation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2)?

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers: `%s` and/or `%[...]`, always include a max characters modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  Those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This will avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here

```
char *file_name;
char *new_name;
```

`file_name` and `new_name` are char pointers and they are not initialized, so they do not point to any valid memory location; if you do like

```
scanf("%s", &file_name);
scanf("%s", &new_name);
```

It causes a segmentation fault, as you didn't allocate any memory for `file_name` and `new_name`.

The correct way is to first allocate the memory for `file_name` and `new_name`  and then scan the data

```
char *file_name = malloc(F_SIZE); /* define F_SIZE */
char *new_name = malloc(N_SIZE); /* define the N_SIZE as how much size you want */
```

And now scan the data like

```
scanf("%s",file_name); /* & is not required */
scanf("%s",new_name);
```

And once done with `file_name` and `new_name` don't forget to free the dynamic memory by calling `free()` to avoid memory leak, e.g.

```
free(file_name);
free(new_name);
```

**Side Note** :  your compiler could have warned you about

```
scanf("%s", &file_name); /* & is not needed */
```

like

> format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has
>   type ‘char **’

Also about

```
char *file_name; /* uninitialized */
```

> ‘file_name’ may be used uninitialized in this function

if you compiled your code with proper flags. I suggest you to compile any basic C code with

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror test.c
```

It helps you lot as sometime one used to take warning literally but they cost more later. So better convert warnings into error by compiling with `-Werror` & go ahead.

Comment: `free(file_name);` and `free(new_name);` give me errors. `runtime error - illegal array, pointer or other operation`

Comment: If `argc==6` means command line input  and after  `file_name = argv[4];` this  `file_name` doesn't holds dynamic memory earlier you allocated & this `free(filke_name)` tries to `free` invalid memory, results in run-time error. Replace `file_name = argv[4];` with  `strcpy(file_name, argv[4]);`

Comment: Similarly  `new_name = argv[5];` --> `strcpy(new_name, argv[5]);`

Comment: See my comment on the question, about calling `scanf()` with the `%s` input format specifier

Answer (score 1):

For these values:

```
printf("What is the pose file called?\n");
scanf("%s", &file_name);

printf("What should we call the newly generated files?\n");
scanf("%s", &new_name);
```

You have declared pointers

```
char *file_name;
char *new_name;
```

So, first of all, the variables are already pointers, so you don't need to use the address of `&` operator :

```
printf("What is the pose file called?\n");
scanf("%s", file_name);

printf("What should we call the newly generated files?\n");
scanf("%s", new_name);
```

second, you have not allocated any memory to hold your character strings, for example :

```
file_name = malloc(50);      // choose appropriate sizes
// check for NULL
new_name = malloc(50);
// check for NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
scanf("%s", &file_name);

scanf("%s", &new_name);
```

To

```
scanf("%s", file_name);

scanf("%s", new_name);
```

You have to allocate memory for **file_name** and **new_name** beforing writing data to them.

And you'd better append `getchar()` after each scanf() to fetch '\n' generated by key **ENTER**.